# Running an executable when the docker-compose exits

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to execute a javascript file using nodejs when the docker container exits. This is what I have got so far and my ***Dockerfile*** contents look like the one below. I am not able to catch the ***SIGINT*** signal during exit and thus not able to run the `int_handler()` function. Is there any issue in the script that I provided below ?

I run the command `docker-compose up` to start the server and then `CTRL + C` to exit.

```
FROM node:10.16.0-slim

ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global

ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/node/.npm-global/bin

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/logs && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

USER node

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 8080

EXPOSE 8523

COPY ./docker-script.sh ./docker-script.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-script.sh"]
```

And the contents of the **docker-script.sh** file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

pid=0

int_handler() {
  echo "handler"
  node deactivator & pid="$!"
}

# setup handlers
trap 'kill ${!}; int_handler' SIGINT

# run application
node server & pid="$!"

# wait forever
while true
do
  tail -f /dev/null & wait ${!}
done
```

My docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6
  web:
    image: myimage/imagexyz:0.9.1
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "80:8081"
     - "443:8524"
    links:
     - mongo 
    depends_on: 
     - mongo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of small details in this that matter.

The most significant is that, when you send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to a foreground `docker-compose up`, it does the equivalent of `docker-compose stop`, which in turn is the equivalent of [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/).  That sends `SIGTERM`, not `SIGINT`.  Changing your `trap` line to catch the right signal will help.

In experimenting with this, once you've sent the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, `docker-compose up` will stop printing container output.  It does still get generated, and you can still see it with `docker-compose logs web` though.

This script seems to be running a lot of things in the background that it doesn't need to, and the one other thing that jumps out at me is that your `int_handler` function starts a background process just as the container is about to exit.  This also has the anti-pattern of running `tail -f` "to keep the container alive", while your application is running as kind of a side effect.

I've gotten reasonable behavior out of this modification of your script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

int_handler() {
  echo "int_handler"
  # node deactivator

  # forcibly exit the script (and the container)
  exit 0
}

# trap SIGTERM here, not SIGINT
trap int_handler SIGTERM

echo start

# run the CMD from the Dockerfile or the `docker run` command
"$@" &

# wait for that process to exit
# (don't start an artificial `tail -f`)
# (you must `wait` or else the signal is delayed until
# the process exits on its own)
wait $!
```

And a matching trivial `Dockerfile`:

```sh
FROM alpine
COPY script /
ENTRYPOINT ["/script"]
CMD ["sleep", "15"]
```

If the `trap` function doesn't `exit`, then anything in the entrypoint script after the final `wait` will execute.  You could use this if you want to unconditionally clean up.  This variant always prints `stop` even if you `docker stop` the container, and exits with the exit status from the script.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
trap 'kill $pid' SIGTERM
echo start
"$@" &
pid=$!
wait $pid
rc=$?
echo stop
exit $rc
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something, but if you need to use `&` to put the command in the background, that means that if you don't use `&` the execution of the script will stay at that point until the process is closed one way or another. Then you can print or do whatever you need, without having to use `wait`, right?

Comment: If a foreground process is running, [a `trap` won't trigger until it exits](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11), which is why here you need to start the process in the background and then immediately `wait` for it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Maybe I misunderstood OP's requirements, but I thought the idea was to do something after the process' exit, not right before it? That's why I said that you could have no trap and just do the operations sequentially

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thanks